# AMP reset selected option after user hits back button

Tags: amp-html

I use standard select code. On select it shows another elements based on value.

```
<select on="change:AMP.setState({ option: event.value })">
<option value="0" >choose</option>
<option value="9">blue</option>
<option value="10">brown</option>
<option value="11">green</option>
</select>

<a on="tap:AMP.setState({ klasa: 10101 })" rel="nofollow" class="button addtocart" hidden="" [hidden]="option != 9" href="/link1">link1</a>
<a on="tap:AMP.setState({ klasa: 10101 })" rel="nofollow" class="button addtocart" hidden="" [hidden]="option != 10" href="/link2">link2</a>
<a on="tap:AMP.setState({ klasa: 10101 })" rel="nofollow" class="button addtocart" hidden="" [hidden]="option != 11" href="/link3">link3</a>
```

My problem: Visitor can choose option, link is then unhidden based on selection. After click on link, user goes to another page. After hitting back button, the option is still selected (that would be ok), however, all buttons are hidden as if option 0 was selected.

I tried using "selected" on option 0 but it does not stay after hitting back button.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Can you share the code that gets triggered after users choose an option ?

Comment: @StefanyNewman hi, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever users click the "Back" button they access a weird browser cache which caches form elements like inputs, selects, etc.

To reverse it, set the default value of the `select` when users click on the link.

You assign the `selectedOption` variable the value of  `1` which then the `[selected]` amp-bind attribute checks and if it is higher than `0` it sets the select to `choose` just before the user it redirected, so when they hit "back" it is in its default state.

```
  <select on="change:AMP.setState({ option: event.value })">
<option value="0" selected [selected]="selectedOption > 0 ">choose</option>
<option value="9">blue</option>
<option value="10">brown</option>
<option value="11">green</option>
</select>

<a on="tap:AMP.setState({ klasa: 10101, selectedOption: 1 })" 
   rel="nofollow" 
   class="button addtocart"  href="https://example.com"
   hidden="" 
   [hidden]="option != 9" >link1</a>
<a on="tap:AMP.setState({ klasa: 10101, selectedOption: 1 })" 
   rel="nofollow" class="button addtocart" href="https://example.com"
   hidden="" [hidden]="option != 10" >link2</a>
<a on="tap:AMP.setState({ klasa: 10101, selectedOption: 1 })" 
   rel="nofollow" 
   class="button addtocart" href="https://example.com"
   hidden="" [hidden]="option != 11" >link3</a>
```

I only manage to get it to work on the first "back" button, so if the user clicks "back" the first time, the select is refreshed, if they click it twice, it is not, but hopefully it will help you.

Comment: HI,thank you.  I thought about it before but I could not make it work. Based on your example I used selectedOption== 0 and on:tap selectedOption: 0. This works only once as you said. Isnt this a bug then? I mean that unhidden elements stay same after hitting back button?

Comment: Happy to help. You are right, it could be a bug. I guess working 1 time is better than none, heh. Chances are, less users would hit the back button twice. But I suggest you file a bug issue in the AMP Project Github page about it and then link it here.

Comment: do you have any update on this issue, from second time onwards it's not working, any workarounds for this